# What is the right way to remove the thin space that appears between adjacent rules when viewed in a PDF viewer?

Tags: rules

When rules are placed next to each other, a thin space appears between them. I'd like to remove the space. What is the best method to do so?

Minimal example:

```
\setbox0=\hbox{\vrule height10pt width10pt}
\vbox{\offinterlineskip
    \hbox{\copy0\copy0}
    \hbox{\copy0\copy0}
}
\bye
```

This results in the following.

[image: Four square rules in a square with thin spaces]

Looking at the disassembled .dvi that results, it appears that there is actually no space in the file. Here's the relevant portion:

```
  push:
    down: -10pt
    push:
      setrule: 10pt 10pt
      setrule: 10pt 10pt
    pop:
    down: 10pt
    push:
      setrule: 10pt 10pt
      setrule: 10pt 10pt
    pop:
  pop:
```

Similar results are obtained replacing the `\copy0` with `\unhcopy0` or simply duplicating the `\vrule`.

There are several ways I can think to deal with this but all feel hackish:

1. Set box 0 to the desired size but set the rule to a larger amount (e.g., .15pt) and shrink the box as necessary. `\setbox0=\vbox to10pt{\hbox to10pt{\vrule width10.15pt height10.15pt\hss}\vss}`;
2. Similar to 1, but explicitly set the box dimensions. `\setbox0=\hbox{\vrule width10.15pt height10.15pt} \ht0=10pt \wd0=10pt`;
3. Similar to 2, but use the depth. `\setbox0=\hbox{\vrule width10.15pt height10pt depth.15pt} \dp0=0pt \wd0=10pt`
4. Add explicit `\kern-.15pt` between boxes.

Is there a canonical solution to this problem?

Comment: Pixel rounding of the PDF viewer. The white line is only visible at certain magnifications.

Comment: Right. I haven't tried printing this, but I'd like it to look good in as a PDF too. (I guess I should have made that more clear.)

Comment: It's a characteristic of your PDF viewer - not the PDF. And different viewers have a preference for procuding different forms of artefacts.